# mongodb queries both with AND and OR

Tags: mongodb

can I use combination of OR and AND in mongodb queries?

the code below doesn't work as expected

```
db.things.find({
           $and:[
                {$or:[
                     {"first_name" : "john"}, 
                     {"last_name" : "john"}
                ]},
                {"phone": "12345678"}
            ]});
```

**database content:**

```
> db.things.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe8734ac27bc8be56947d60"), "first_name" : "john", "last_name" : "hersh", "phone" : "2222" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe8736dc27bc8be56947d61"), "first_name" : "john", "last_name" : "hersh", "phone" : "12345678" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe8737ec27bc8be56947d62"), "first_name" : "elton", "last_name" : "john", "phone" : "12345678" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe8738ac27bc8be56947d63"), "first_name" : "eltonush", "last_name" : "john", "phone" : "5555" }
```

when querying the above query - i get nothing!

```
> db.things.find({$and:[{$or:[{"first_name" : "john"}, {"last_name" : "john"}]},{"phone": "12345678"}]});
>
```

I'm using mongo 1.8.3

Comment: I'm guessing this is an issue with the old version of MongoDB you're running. Your query seems to work with 2.0.6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe $and is only supported in MongoDB v2.0+. I'm surprised that the console accepted the expression in the first place. I'll try to recreate against a 1.8 server I have.

Also check [10Gen's Advanced Query Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-$and) for `$and`.

*Update*

I entered your sample data into both a v1.8x and v2.0x MongoDB server. The query works on the v2.0x and fails on the v1.8x. This confirms my (and Miikka's) suspicions that the problem is with `$and` and your server version.

I found a (arguably) clever workaround for this on the Web [here](http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/12/21/mongodb-query-tricks). I hope this helps.

-SethO

Answer (score 74):

```
db.things.find({
    $and: [
        {
            $or: [
                {"first_name": "john"},
                {"last_name": "john"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "Phone": "12345678"
        }
    ]
})
```

**AND** takes an array of 2 expressions **OR** , phone.
**OR** takes an array of 2 expressions first_name , last_name.

**AND**

- **OR**
- first_name
- last_name
- Phone Number.

Note: Upgrade to latest version of MongoDB, if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 51):

Shorter to use an implicit AND operation:

```
db.things.find({
    $or : [ 
        {"first_name": "john"},
        {"last_name": "john"}
    ],
    "phone": "12345678"         
})
```

Comment: $or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects

Answer (score 22):

This is possible in following manner (mongodb 3.4)

Here is the good example

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-operator

```
        db.getCollection('tbl_menu_items').find({
        $and : [
            { $or : [ { price : 0.99 }, { price : 1.99 } ] },
            { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
        ]
    } )
```

This query will select all documents where:

the price field value equals 0.99 or 1.99, and
the sale field value is equal to true or the qty field value is less than 20.

Here is the example of $and condition with $or query i.e matching any of condition for example

consider following query...

```
        db.getCollection('tbl_menu_items').find(

        { '$or': 
           [ { '$and': 
                [ { location: { '$in': [ ObjectId("588054c63879f2e767a1d553")  ] } },
                  { is_ryward: 1 },
                  { points_reqiured_to_redeem_reward: { '$lte': 500 } } ] },
             { '$and': 
                [ { location: { '$in': [ ObjectId("588054c63879f2e767a1d553")  ] } },
                  { is_freebie: 1 } ] } ] }
        )
```

This query will select all documents where:

location array in 588054c63879f2e767a1d553 and is_ryward = 1 and     points_reqiured_to_redeem_reward < 500

Or

location array in 588054c63879f2e767a1d553 and is_freebie

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can write your query like this:

```
const query = {};
query['phone'] = '12345678';
query['$or'] = [
  { "first_name": "john" },
  { "last_name": "john" }
];
db.things.find(query);
```