# How to use $and & $or together in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want to implement the following SQL query on MongoDB:

SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM marvel WHERE likes > 10 AND (by = "professorX" OR title = "X-Men");
```

MongoDB:

```
db.marvel.find({
  $and: 
    [
      {"likes": {$gt: 10}}, 
      {$or: 
        [
          {"by": "professorX"},
          {"title": "X-Men"}
        ]
      }
    ]          
})
```

Is there a way to optimize the same query in MongoDB?

Comment: you can refer this question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196101/mongodb-queries-both-with-and-and-or)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.marvel.find({
  $and: 
    [
      {likes: {$gt: 10},
      { $or : [ { by : "professorX"}, { title : "X-title" } ] }

    ]          
})
```