# MongoDB query using $and and $or

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I trying to perform a query using $and and $or in MongoDB. Sadly I've had no luck. I found several similar questions posted here on Stack Overflow, this one came closest.

[mongodb queries both with AND and OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196101/mongodb-queries-both-with-and-and-or/42340850)

Unfortunately the solution did not work for me. I want to allow user to search by project id or title. I do have code that check if the q variable past in is a valid ObjectId before I include it.

Here is my query:

```
Project.find({
   $and : [
       { $or : [ { title: {$regex : req.body.q} }, { _id: req.body.q } ] },
       { userID: req.session.userID }
   ]
   }).then(project => {
      console.log(project);    
   });
```

sample document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afb583e8341f161a0c950af"), "title" : "Learn Node.js", "status" : "In Progress", "createdOn" : "2014-06-05 22:39:00.000Z" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe8736dc27bc8be56947d61"), "title" : "Learn MongoDB", "status" : "In Progress", "createdOn" : "2014-06-05 22:39:00.000Z" }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You title is a $regex on the ObjectID? I get the `_id` check but not following the title... can you replace that title check with another and see if it works? That would narrow it down. Unless your title contains the ID?

Comment: Please post some example documents

Comment: Is userID a `ObjectId`? Can you please post the `Project` schema?

Comment: Hi Sridhar, no the userID is just a random alphanumeric string.

Comment: Akrion, the $regex is not the ObjectID, the _id is the ObjectID.

Comment: Which search is not working ? title or _id ? In case of object id you have to convert your passed string into object id before passing to the filter.

Comment: Veeram, both search is not working. It should according to the documentation it should work https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: what doesn't work here https://mongoplayground.net/p/6b61eWpPk5X???.... And put `@` while commenting

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet everything works as expected in the link you'd provided. It must be something else that in my code. Thank for you help!

Comment: cast your ids to objectid then it will work... are you using mongoose?

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet thank you for your help. I'm able to get my code working. It was my logic that was off.

Comment: awesome Cheers!!!

Comment: I changed my query to this title: { $regex: req.body.q, $options: 'i' } to get the text search to work.